# ¿Como crear una nueva variable usando la condicional if else?

Tags: r, condiciones, else

Tengo el siguiente vector:

```
set.seed(1)
y<-sample(1:50, 20, T)
```

Y deseo categorizarlas y crear un nuevo vector. Es decir, si el valor de `y` está entre 1 y 15 asignar el valor de 1 al vector `x`. Asimismo, si está entre 16 y 35 asignar al vector `x` el valor de 2 y por último si está en el rango de 36 a 50 asignar el valor de 3 al vector `x`.

Todo usando la condicional if else.

```
if("Condición 1") {
"Función a ejecutar si Condición 1 es verdadero."
} else if("Condición 2") {
"Función a ejecutar si Condición 2 es verdadero."
} else {
"Función a ejecutar si Condición 1 y Condición 2 son falsas." 
}
```

No se como hacerlo. Si sé como hacerlo si aplico la función `ifelse()` o con `case_when()`. Me surge la duda de como hacerlo con esa sintaxis, ya que en esencia lo que hace el `ifelse()` y el `case_when()` es lo mismo.

**Muchas gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, el `if` común, no es lo más adecuado para esto, ya que en realidad solo evalúa una única condición, para usarlo necesitarías implementar un bucle por cada valor del vector y verificar la condición en cada uno.

```
x <- c()
for (v in y) {

  if (v >= 1 && v <=15) {
    x <- c(x,1)  
  } else {
    if (v >= 16 && v<=35) {
      x <- c(x,2)  
    }
    else {
      x <- c(x,3)  
    }
  }
}
```

Es preferible usar, como dices, el `ifelse()` que es vectorizado, pero como tienes tres condiciones, necesitas "anidar" los `ifelse()`, por ejemplo:

```
x <- ifelse(y >= 1 & y <=15, 
            1,
            ifelse(y >= 16 & y <= 35,
                   2,
                   3)
            )
```

Validamos el primer rango, si no se cumple, validamos el segundo y así, si tuviéramos más. De cualquier manera, todavía más sencillo, es usar `findInterval()` dónde simplemente tenemos que definir el valor inicial de cada rango y la función simplemente no retorna el número de estos:

```
x <- findInterval(y, c(0, 16, 36))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.

Comment: Patrico, una pregunta adicional. 
Por qué usa el `&&` y no solamente el `&`?

Comment: @CESARHUAMANININAHUANCA, en el contexto de tu pregunta es indistinto. Pero, pare ale `if` es más razonable usar la versión simple. Esto tal vez lo aclare: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167412/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-control-de-flujo-en-un-lenguaje-que-es-enteramente-vectorial

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio.

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una opción forzando la iteración sobre el vector `y` con `sapply()` y una función anónima.

```
sapply(y, function(x) { 
  if (x > 1 & x <= 15) { "chico"} 
  else if (x > 15 & x <= 35) {"mediano"} 
  else {"grande"}
})
```

Si bien se podría esperar que al ser un vector el input la función operara de manera vectorizada, en este caso es necesario iterar explícitamente con `sapply()`. Un `for` también funcionaría. El riesgo de usar `sapply()` en scripts cuya ejecución no vas a estar supervisando es que es el output cambia de estructura para acomodar los datos. En el caso de ejemplo regresa un vector de la clase `character`, pero si algún valor de `y` no cumpliera ninguna de las condiciones (en este caso difícilmente ocurra por el `else`) entonces regresaría silenciosamente una lista para poder acomodar los `NULL`. Así que usar con cuidado!

Si vas por esta ruta podrías usar `vapply()` en lugar de `sapply()`, para que haga una verificación del tipo de salida y, en caso de el output no sea el esperado regrese un error en lugar de una lista/matriz o lo que sea que a `sapply()` se le antoje regresarnos.

```
vapply(y, function(x) { 
  if (x > 1 & x <= 15) { "chico"} 
  else if (x > 15 & x <= 35) {"mediano"} 
  else {"grande"}
}, 
FUN.VALUE = character(1))
```

El argumento `FUN.VALUE =` especifica el tipo de output. Si no se cumple da un error. Comparemos los casos siguientes, en los que elimino el `else` final, algunos valores de `y` son evaluados como `NULL` y  `sapply()` produce una lista:

```
vapply(y, function(x) { 
  if (x > 1 & x <= 15) { "chico"} 
  else if (x > 15 & x <= 35) {"mediano"} 
  #else {"grande"}
}, 
FUN.VALUE = character(1))

Error in vapply(y, function(x) { : Los valores deben ser de longitud 1, 
  pero el resultado FUN(X [[2]]) es la longitud 0
```

Me regresa un error.

```
class(
sapply(y, function(x) { 
  if (x > 1 & x <= 15) { "chico"} 
  else if (x > 15 & x <= 35) {"mediano"} 
  #else {"grande"}
})
)
[1] "list"
```

Me regresa una lista.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias mpaladino. Que buen aporte.