# ¿Cómo tengo que crear una función que devuelva TRUE si un número es **mayor estricto** que todos los elementos de un vector?

Tags: r, funciones, rstudio

estoy aprendiendo a programar en R y me piden crear una función que devuelva TRUE si un número es **mayor estricto** que todos los elementos de un vector. Deberá recibir como argumentos el vector y el número.

Tengo que resolver el ejercicio usando el operador `>` dentro de la función junto con `sum` del vector de booleanos resultante de la comparación. La función ahora se llamará `mayor.vector.op`. No puedo utilizar bucles.

En resumen, tengo que crear una función en la que al meter, por ejemplo, un numero: 8 y un vector: c(9,10,5,11), nos devuelva FALSE. Sin embargo, si introducimos el numero 8 y un vector c(1,2,6,7) nos tiene que devolver TRUE ya que 8 es mayor que todos los elementos del vector.

Si alguién me pudiese explicar y ayudar con esto lo agradecería enormemente. Os dejo el código de la función que he probado a hacer pero no pasa las fases de prueba.

```
mayor.vector.op <- function(v, numero){
    if (numero > v){
    sum(v)
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}
```

Si hago esto de aquí arriba, al meter un vector de más de 1 elemento me devuelve un warning ya que solo hace la comprobación en la posición 1 del vector, y quiero que lo haga en todos los elementos del vector, como podría hacer eso?

Aquí os dejo las pruebas que tiene que pasar la función para ser válida:

```
mayor.vector.op(c(5,8,34),6) == FALSE
mayor.vector.op(c(7,8,6),10) == TRUE
mayor.vector.op(c(-5),-7) == FALSE
mayor.vector.op(c(-5),5) == TRUE
```

Comment: He visto que se puede hacer con ifelse, para poder hacer comprobaciones de numeros con vectores de más de 1 elemento. Alguién sabe si quisiera hacer eso con un bucle for y while como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Creo que esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167412/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-control-de-flujo-en-un-lenguaje-que-es-enteramente-vectorial responde a tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias ya lo he solucionado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código va bien encaminado, puedes usar la función length para ver el largo de un vector, en tu caso, puedes guardar el vector de lógicos en una variable y preguntar el caso en que la suma de los lógicos (TRUE) sea igual al largo de tu vector numero, eso significaría que se cumple en todo el vector, en caso contrario devolver FALSE

```
mayor.vector.op <- function(v, numero) {
  
  logicos = numero > v
  if (sum(logicos) == length(logicos))
    return(T)
  else
    return(F)
  
}
```