# Como contar caracteres con un condicional if else en R?

Tags: r, condiciones, else, substring

Estoy intentando extraer ciertos caracteres de un vector llamado "identhog" que se encuentra en la tabla "E". Pero quiero extraer ciertos caracteres dependiendo de la logintud del texto que se encuentra en el vector. Asi si la longitud del vector es 10 deseo extraer ciertos caracteres, y si es 11 deseo extraer otros caracteres en distinta posicion.

```
if (nchar(E$identhog)==10) {
  E <- mutate(E,prueba2= substr(E$identhog, 2, 6))
  } else {
  E <- mutate(E, prueba2=substr(E$identhog, 3,7))
  }
```

Estoy usando un condicional IF ELSE, pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

"Warning message:
In if (nchar(E$identhog) == 10) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

y solo cumple la primera condición de:

```
E <- mutate(E,prueba2= substr(E$identhog, 2, 6))
```

Como puedo solucionar este problema? Tengo entendido que IF ELSE funciona con vectores booleanos por lo que debería funcionar mi código, pero no entiendo por qué no es así

También intenté ocupar el siguiente comando:

```
 ifelse((nchar(E$identhog)==10), 
     E <- mutate(E,prueba2= substr(E$identhog, 2, 6)), 
     E <- mutate(E, prueba2=substr(E$identhog, 3,7)))
```

Pero al tener una base de datos muy grande solo se quedó procesando todos los datos y no obtuvé un resultado.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola @Alexis SM!

Tu problema es debido a que la condición `nchar(E$identhog)==10` devuelve un vector lógico de longitud igual a la de `E$identhog`

Hay varias maneras de solucionar el problema; una de ellas es introduciendo un `for`:

```
for (i in 1:length(E$identhog){
     if (nchar(E$identhog[i])==10){
        E$prueba2[i] <- substr(E$identhog[i], 2, 6)
     } else{
        E$prueba2[i] <- substr(E$identhog[i], 3,7))
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Por el lado del `if()` debo decirte que espera como condición un vector de un solo elemento, y en tu caso estas generando una condición con múltiples valores lógicos, coincidente con el número de filas de `E`. Como referencia te sugiero que veas: [¿Cómo funciona el control de flujo en un lenguaje que es enteramente vectorial?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167412/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-control-de-flujo-en-un-lenguaje-que-es-enteramente-vectorial)

Ciertamente puedes emplear un ciclo y validar la condición en cada elemento como te han comentado ya, o bien puedes usar la función vectorial `ifelse()` pero de la siguiente forma:

```
E %>%
  mutate(dato = ifelse(nchar(identhog)==10, 
                       substr(identhog, 2, 6), 
                       substr(identhog, 3, 7)))
```